# How to clear cell filled colour using Excel macro by specifying range instead of UsedRange option

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with the following problem:
How can I clear a cell filled color by specifying range or infinite range in Excel VBA instead of using `UsedRange` to clear filled color?

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Cells.Interior.Color = -4142
```

Answer (score 4):

To clear a fill color, don't reset the color code; change the `.Interior.Pattern` to xlNone.

```
with Worksheets("Sheet2")
    with .cells(1, 1).currentregion
        with .resize(.rows.count -1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
            .Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        end with
    end with
end with
```

Comment: Okay..thanks -..i will correct it and how about range..because i don't want my header row colour to get clear..can you please help me..

Comment: I don't recall any mention of a header row in your question but you can take a look at the modification I made above.

Comment: oops..but i didn't mention specifically in description.. but any way thanks buddy it is working the code u gave me and can i ask one more favour ....is it possible to write in single line..:-) just for my understanding.. –